# how can i get ibook to display data queried from online database

Tags: database, ibooks

I have an ibook that I am trying to get to pull back a table of data from my database in the cloud, on my server. If I put the main.html file on my server and browse to it with my web browser it works like a champ returning a table of data, but when I put this html as my main.html file in the Info.plist it does not display the table in the ibook. What am I missing?

Here is my html file which is in the widget in the ibook html widget on a page of the book

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://myserver.com/ibook_widgets/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'http://myserver.com/ibook_widgets/getdata.php?id=4',
  data: 'json',
  beforeSend: function() {
    // before send the request, displays a "Loading..." messaj in the element where the server response will be placed
    $('#resp').html('Loading...');
  },
  timeout: 10000,        // sets timeout for the request (10 seconds)
  error: function(xhr, status, error) { alert('Error: '+ xhr.status+ ' - '+ error); },
  success: function(response) { $('#listhere').html(response); }
});

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="listhere" style="border: solid black 1px; background-color:red;">Replace this text with html table from php file</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my php file which is on my server

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 */



$dbhostname='myserver.com';
$dbusername='usr';
$dbpassword='pwd';
$dbname='mydatabase';


$con = mysql_connect($dbhostname,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);


// check for post data
if (isset($_POST["id"])) 
{
$inValue = $_POST['id'];



$sql = 'select id, btn_txt from mytable where parent_id = '.$inValue.' order by btn_txt';



$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if (!empty($result)) 
{
    // check for empty result
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
    {

        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);


        $btntxt = $row['btn_txt'];


            $result1 = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            // check for empty result
            if (!empty($result1)) 
            {
                // check for empty result
                if (mysql_num_rows($result1) > 0) 
                {
                    // looping through all results
                    // products node


                    $tmpStr =  "<table border='1'><tr><th>Tap A Row To See Details</th></tr>";

                    // show select box input_select_4
                    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
                    {
                        $tmpStr = $tmpStr . "<tr><th><a href=\"http://myserver.com/ibook_widgets/getdata.php?id=". $row1["id"] . "\" target=\"_self\">" . $row1["btn_txt"] . "</a></th></tr>";

                    }

                    $tmpStr = $tmpStr . "</table>";

                    echo $tmpStr;
                    // echoing JSON response
                   ///echo json_encode($tmpStr);





            mysql_close($con);



                    // echoing JSON response
                   ////echo json_encode($response);


                } 
            }

        } 
    } 
}

?>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Your code is vulnerable for SQL Injection, you're *not* escaping values before using them in your SQL statements, which may lead to exposure of sensitive information and data loss. Read this site for some examples and what can happen: http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

Comment: Thanks for the couple of replies... both are valid comments, but not the answer to the question I asked... I eventually figured out the issue... as stated below, it had to do with CORS.

Answer (score 2):

After many hours of research it has to do with CORS  Cross-Origin Resource Sharing

I had to add the following header line to my php file on my server and bingo it all worked.

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  *");
```

For more details on this, Here is an explanation of CORS from

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-cors-from-jquery

Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a W3C spec that allows cross-domain communication from the browser. By building on top of the XmlHttpRequest object, CORS allows developers to work with the same idioms as same-domain requests.

The use-case for CORS is simple. Imagine the site alice.com has some data that the site bob.com wants to access. This type of request traditionally wouldn’t be allowed under the browser’s same origin policy. However, by supporting CORS requests, alice.com can add a few special response headers that allows bob.com to access the data.

As you can see from this example, CORS support requires coordination between both the server and client. Luckily if you are a client-side developer, you are shielded from most of these details. The rest of this article shows how clients can make cross-origin requests, and how servers can configure themselves to support CORS.